# Derivative parameric equation

Tags: derivatives, parametric

I would like to compute the derivative of the following parametric equations w.r.t $a$ and $b$:

$x=a~ \text{cos}(t)$ and $y= b~ \text{sin}(t)$ with $t \in [0, b]$.

Derivative w.r.t $a$ are easy to compute : $d_a x = \text{cos}(t)$, $d_a y = 0$  with $t \in [0, b]$.

However, the ones w.r.t $b$ are somewhat not intuitive since $t$ depends on $b$.

For example, if $t=b$ then $d_b x =-ab \text{sin}(b)$

I would appreciate if someone has insight on how to compute these derivatives.

Thank you.

Reda E.

Comment: $t$ doesn't depend on $b$; it's still an independent variable.  Its range depends on $b$ but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Actually it does, because $d_b x = \partial_b x + \partial_t x d_b t$.

The last term $d_b t$ shows the dependence.

Comment: You must first clarify which are the dependent and independent variables.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, $t$ doesn't depend on $b.$ Or at least not for most of its values. It depends on $b$ only once in the interval $[0,1/b].$ Otherwise it doesn't. So the derivatives are as before.

Comment: Actually it does, because $d_b x = \partial_b x + \partial_t x d_b t$.

The last term $d_b t$ shows the dependence.

Comment: @Reda I see you've changed that interval. In any case, as I've said, $t$ is a function of $b$ only at the right endpoint of your interval. If you need the derivative at this endpoint, set $t=b$ and differentiate.

Comment: what if $t=b-\varepsilon$, it is also a special case